# Update object key using destructuring

Tags: javascript

I am trying to update an Object key using destructuring like this

```
let user = {
    name: "raju",
    age: 40,
    sex: "male"
}

name = "vvvv"

user1 = {name, ...user}

console.log(user1)
```

But it is not updating `name == 'vvvv'` in `user1`.

I am confused, need some help on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Later property names will overwrite earlier property names. Just like a duplicate `name` below results in the last one being included in the object:

```js
console.log({
  name: 'foo',
  name: 'bar'
});
```

When using spread syntax, you should put the properties you want to overwrite the others *last*:

```
user1 = {...user, name}
```

Answer (score 3):

Order matters, you have to put the updated property at last position:

```js
let user = {
    name: "raju",
    age: 40,
    sex: "male"
}

name = "vvvv"

user1 = {...user, name}

console.log(user1)
```