# Getting rid of repetitive code for ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am pretty new to react and am making a basic recipe web app. To do so I have to call from an API and edit the URL depending on if the user selects a certain variable.

My problem is I have like 5 display and handleChange functions which are near identical. Is there any to condense this code?

```
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  //1
  const [minProtein, setMinProtein] = useState("");
  //100
  const [maxCarbs, setMaxCarbs] = useState("");
  //100
  const [maxFat, setMaxFat] = useState("");
  //100
  const [number, setNumber] = useState("");
  //800
  const [maxCalories, setMaxCalories] = useState("");
  //display variables booleans
  const [isProtein, setIsProtein] = useState(false);
  const [isCarb, setIsCarb] = useState(false);
  const [isFat, setIsFat] = useState(false);
  const [isNumber, setIsNumber] = useState(false);
  const [isCalories, setIsCalories] = useState(false);
  const oneHundred = range(0, 100); // [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  let URL =
    `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?apiKey=${API_KEY}&${query}` +
    minProtein +
    maxCarbs +
    maxCalories +
    maxFat +
    number;

  async function getData() {
    const response = await fetch(URL);
    const data = await response.json();
    await setResults(data.results);
    console.log(data);
    console.log("data logged ^");
  }
  function displayProtein() {
    setIsProtein(!isProtein);
    setMinProtein("");
  }
  function displayCarb() {
    setIsCarb(!isCarb);
    setMaxCarbs("");
  }
  function displayFat() {
    setIsFat(!isFat);
    setMaxFat("");
  }
  function displayNumber() {
    setIsNumber(!isNumber);
    setNumber("");
  }
  function displayCal() {
    setIsCalories(!isCalories);
    setMaxCalories("");
  }

  function handleChange(e) {
    setQuery(e.target.value);
    console.log(query);
  }

  //pass the set function,e, and the & tag and make a parent function for this
  function handleProteinChange(e) {
    let temp = e.target.value;
    setMinProtein("&minProtein=" + temp);
    console.log(query);
  }
  function handleCarbChange(e) {
    let temp = e.target.value;
    setMaxCarbs("&maxCarbs=" + temp);
    console.log(query);
  }
  function handleFatChange(e) {
    let temp = e.target.value;
    setMaxFat("&maxFat=" + temp);
    console.log(query);
  }
  function handleNumberChange(e) {
    let temp = e.target.value;
    setNumber("&number=" + temp);
    console.log(query);
  }
  function handleCalChange(e) {
    let temp = e.target.value;
    setMaxCalories("&minCalories=" + temp);
    console.log(query);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Recipe App </h1>
      <section>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="Query"
          onKeyPress={(event) => {
            if (event.key === "Enter") {
              getData();
            }
          }}
        />
      </section>
      {/* //protein section copy */}
      <NutritionParam
        name="Min Protein"
        bool={isProtein}
        setBool={setIsProtein}
        handleTextChange={handleProteinChange}
        handleDisplay={displayProtein}
      />
      {/* Carb section */}
      <NutritionParam
        name="Max Carbs"
        bool={isCarb}
        setBool={setIsCarb}
        handleTextChange={handleCarbChange}
        handleDisplay={displayCarb}
      />
      {/* //fat section */}
      <NutritionParam
        name="Max Fat"
        bool={isFat}
        setBool={setIsFat}
        handleTextChange={handleFatChange}
        handleDisplay={displayFat}
      />
      {/* calorie section */}
      <NutritionParam
        name="Max Calories"
        bool={isCalories}
        setBool={setIsCalories}
        handleTextChange={handleCalChange}
        handleDisplay={displayCal}
        placeholder={"50 to 800kcal"}
      />
      {/* shows number of results */}
      <NutritionParam
        name="Number"
        bool={isNumber}
        setBool={setIsNumber}
        handleTextChange={handleNumberChange}
        handleDisplay={displayNumber}
        placeholder={"1 to 100"}
      />
```

Below is the nutrition param component

```
import React from "react";

export default function NutritionParam(props) {
  return (
    <section>
      {props.bool && (
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={props.handleTextChange}
          placeholder={props.placeholder || "1 to 100g"}
        />
      )}
      <button onClick={() => props.handleDisplay()}>{props.name}</button>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use an object and destructing to work with your properties rather than handling each one individually.

Comment: Sorry pretty new to this stuff. I know what objects are and destructuring (loosely) is but could you give me an example of how they would apply here. Would really appreciate the help

Comment: Here's a stackoverflow QA where they are updating an object using destructing (aka spread operator) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60465636/update-object-key-using-destructuring

Comment: And here's a simple example of using the spread operator to update state within React: https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/using-the-spread-operator-in-react-setstate-c8a14fc51be1